# How to convert CompressedImage to Image?

Tags: ros, compressed-image-transport, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to convert CompressedImage to Image.

```
rosrun image_transport republish raw in:=/image_raw  compressed out:=/image_raw_converted
```

Then, I could got image_raw_converted which is CompressedImage and 1/10 data size.
I would like to use image_raw_converted as Image. So,

```
rosrun image_transport republish compressed in:=/image_raw_converted raw out:=/image_raw_converted2
```

However, the data size increases by 10 times.

Is there any way to convert CompressedImage to Image and also decrease the data size?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255039/how-to-convert-compressedimage-to-image?/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. Compression is the way to reduce the size of the data footprint while recording data. This is the principle that governs video data as well, known as [codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec). The actual data of a recorded movie is lot larger than the one you stream or watch on your computer.

I believe that ros does a pretty good job of compressing incoming image data and hence you see a bloat in the image size when you decompress it frame by frame. You can read the source code of compressions [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_transport_plugins/blob/indigo-devel/compressed_image_transport/src/compressed_publisher.cpp)

If you want to compress it further I would recommend use ros to generate all the images and then compress everything using a video codec using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/). There is information about that on [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/ffmpeg-create-video-from-images).

---

Originally posted by [tushar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29413/tushar/) with karma: 26 on 2017-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2017-02-21**:
Thank you for replying.

I would like to ask that it is possible to convert the image in type of CompressedImage into the image in type of Image.

**Comment by [tushar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29413/tushar/) on 2017-02-21**:
[Image view](http://wiki.ros.org/image_view) is the package you are looking for. It will let you subscribe to the topic that is publishing images and save the output to files.

**Comment by [anonymous38087](https://answers.ros.org/users/38087/anonymous38087/) on 2019-04-02**:
Is there any method for converting `sensor_msgs/image` data to `sensor_msgs/CompressedImage`?